Docker hot reload react
I have been having problems being able to use hot reload in my project with docker. This is my configuration:
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: m_2024_almacen_backend
    ports:
      - 3007:3007
  frontend:
    build:
      context: m_2024_almacen_web
      target: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./m_2024_almacen_web/src:/app/src
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    env_file:
      - ./m_2024_almacen_web/.env



Dockerfile frontend:
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:16.20.2 AS development

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

RUN npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY . /app

ENV CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

CMD ["npm", "run", "nodemon"]



In docker desktop i can see the mounts :
enter image description here
And the changes are applied to the container files but to view them in the explorer I have to restart the container
enter image description here
I have watched several videos trying to follow the configuration but I don't get results.

Can you just npm run nodemon, without involving Docker at all?

Yes, if I run my project locally the hot reload works correctly, the problem is when I run it with docker

...so can you remove Docker from the setup?  What benefits are you getting from Docker here?

"view them in the explorer"... what is this?

the web browser
